# date picker dialog to show full month name

Tags: android

I want to show full month name in date picker dialog. I have tried in many ways didn't get success let me know if it's any way.

**Currently I have this:**

15, AUG 2014

**What I want to get:**

15, AUGUST 2014

**Here is my code:**

```
private void showDailogfordateEnd(final TextView textView)
{

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int day =calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month =calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year =calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    dpd = new DatePickerDialog(ProgressReportActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth ,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            eday=day;
            emonth=month;
            eyear=year;
            textView.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year);

            selcetedMonth=month;
            selectedDay=day;
            selectedYear=year;

            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            Date date=calendar.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            EndDate=simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
            eD=simpleDateFormat1.format(date);

        }
    }, year,month,day);
    //((ViewGroup) dpd.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android"));

    dpd.show();
```

Comment: Due to 1 reput i didn't able to post image.

Comment: Posting code as images is a bad idea. It makes hard to others to reproduce your problem. That being said, check the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). It has very useful information

Answer (score 0):

Change: `"yyyy-MM-dd "` to `"yyyy-MMMM-dd "`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```